# IO String and IO Data type

Tags: haskell

I have this:

```
data SomeData = SomeData Int Int

getDataFromUser :: SomeData
getDataFromUser = do
{
    read (getLine)::SomeData;
}
```

This doesnt compile : Expected type String Actual type IO String

How I can fix it? I need this data deserialization...

Comment: The answers below are "more helpful" in the sense that they address the conceptual problem you have; however, you may also be interested in the "less helpful" fix, `getDataFromUser :: IO SomeData; getDataFromUser = readLn`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to treat `getLine` as a String, but it's an `IO String` — an IO action that, when executed, produces a string. You can execute it and get the resulting value from inside a `do` block by using `<-`, but since `getDataFromUser` does IO, its type has to be `IO SomeData`:

```
getDataFromUser :: IO SomeData
getDataFromUser = do
  line <- getLine
  return $ read line
```

More broadly, I would recommend reading a tutorial on IO in Haskell, like Learn You a Haskell's [chapter on IO](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output); it's very different from the IO facilities of most other languages, and it can take some time to get used to how things fit together; it's hard to convey a full understanding with answers to specific questions like this :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to read up more on how Haskell IO works and make sure you understand it.

A couple of points on your example.  If you want to use `read` to deserialize to `SomeData`, you need to provide a `Read` instance for the type.  You can use the default one:

```
data SomeData = SomeData Int Int deriving (Read)
```

Second: `getLine` is an `IO` action that returns a `String`, not a `String`; since `read` wants a `String`, this is the cause of your error.  This is closer to what you want:

```
getDataFromUser :: IO SomeData
getDataFromUser = do str <- getLine
                     return (read str)
```

This can be simplified to the following, but make sure you understand the above example before you worry too much about this:

```
getDataFromUser :: IO SomeData
getDataFromUser = liftM read getLine
```